# Find Last Column used in excel sheet using VBA in Microsoft Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to operate on an excel sheet using VBA from MS Word.

I wasn't able to understand why I get error when I try to catch LastCol value:

```
Dim mXL As Object
Dim mWBook As Object
Dim mSheet As Object
Dim C As Long, R As Long
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

Set mXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
mXL.Visible = True
Set mWBook = mXL.Workbooks.Open("c:\test\test.xlsx")
Set mSheet = mWBook.sheets(1)
LastCol = mSheet.Cells(1, mSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'THIS ISN'T WORKIMG
LastCol = mSheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column 'This also gives error
```

Comment: Because Word doesn't know what `xlToLeft` and `xlToRight` are, since those are members of the *Excel* object model.

Comment: @BigBen So what's the way? I think there is a way!

Comment: As @BigBen mentioned you can't use Excel's enum with late bound. Use the value of enums instead (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using late-binding, so Word doesn't know what `xlToLeft` and `xlToRight` are, because those are from the *Excel* object model.

Add the following:

```
Const xlToLeft As Long = -4159
Const xlToRight As Long = -4161
```

based on the corresponding values from the [XLDirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection) enum.

Answer (score 1):

As @BigBen mentioned you can't use Excel's enum with late bound. Use the value of enums instead (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection)